# why when i want use EF Power tools for view my model i get error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ef-code-first, dbcontext, fluent, ef-power-tools

Im using EF Code first and i generate my model by "EF 4.x DbContext Fluent Generator for c#" extension in vs2010. but when i want to view my Entity model via EF Power tools i get this error:"Sequence Contains no matching element". is there any idea?

Comment: Have you tried EF Power Tools Beta 3 released a couple days ago? It has a number of fixes to the most common problems.

Comment: I got Beta 3 released also, but my problem didn't fix.

Comment: Seems like this may be answered over here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377687/a-constructible-type-deriving-from-dbcontext-could-not-be-found-in-the-selected

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit too late and not sure if this would help but for others and historic reasons...

> I had the same issue (with Beta 3 - and .NET 4/2010/EF5 etc.) - the
>   solution was relatively simple.
>   **I just moved out the project from the 'solution directory' into the root of the solution**.

I 'learned' that trick from dealings with 'migrations' and PM console - it wouldn't work if you have a lib (entities) - and your startup/executable - while any of the two is in a solution dir somewhere.

Comment: thanks, but my problem exists yet. I move my projects to root of solution but i get that error yet, I have 2 projects, one for my entities and another for Context and mappings. so after moving these 2 projects, in root directory i have 3 directories 1-solution directory 2-Models directory that contains a project for entities and 3-DAL directory that contains a project for context , mapping files. am i correct?

Comment: try with different startup projects - I"m just guessing here - that worked for me - and that's the old problem with migration and powershell - not sure if they're using that but seems so (again guessing)

Comment: @GoranObradovic I'm glad it did

Comment: yeah, thanks, but it was worthless, generated views did not improve startup time not even by 1%

Comment: it worked for me @GoranObradovic :). I noticed it immediately, there was no delay. You can check it out, if you're actually using it, just put breakpoints in the class (generated views) and see if it's called. You might need to some more to enable it (there're more issues)